# Book class: Abstract material fits on a left-hand (verso) page but not on a right-hand (recto) page

Tags: double-sided

I am finalizing my thesis, I wrote my abstract, and I compressed everything to fit nicely on one page. Now I realized that my abstract was on a left-hand page but it needs to be on a right-hand page, so I added a `\cleardoublepage` instruction.

However, after doing so my abstract does not fit on one page anymore. It now has a complete paragraph that spills over to the next page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{vub}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}
\makeatletter

\makeatother
\geometry{textwidth=390pt}

\geometry{bindingoffset=2cm}


\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    % I want a blank page in between title page and abstract
    % I tried the following two commands, both show the same issue
    \cleardoublepage
    \newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

    \cleardoublepage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \input{sections/abstract}
    % ...

\end{document}
```

Even when i add a blank left-hand page with `\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage` instead of `\cleardoublepage`, the problem still persists. It seems like right-hand pages are less long than left-hand pages. Is this even possible?

And this is the `vub` package:

```
\ProvidesPackage{vub}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{adjustbox}
% VUB is in Belgium, we use A4
% Additionally, we use `geometry` to play with margins on the title page
\RequirePackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareBoolOption[false]{spotcolors}
\DeclareComplementaryOption{nospotcolors}{spotcolors}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*{}

\ifvub@spotcolors
\RequirePackage[spotcolors]{vubprivate}
\else
\RequirePackage{vubprivate}
\fi

\newcommand\@faculty{Set a faculty using \textbackslash faculty\{\textit{Engineering Sciences}\}}
\newcommand\@subtitle{}

\newcommand\pretitle[1]{%
  \makeatletter%
  \newcommand\@pretitle{#1}%
  \makeatother%
}

\newcommand\promotors[1]{%
  \makeatletter%
  \newcommand\@promotors{#1}%
  \makeatother%
}

\@ifundefined{faculty}{%
    \newcommand{\faculty}[1]{%
        \makeatletter%
        \renewcommand\@faculty{#1}%
        \makeatother%
    }%
}

\@ifundefined{subtitle}{%
    \newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
        \makeatletter%
        \renewcommand\@subtitle{#1}%
        \makeatother%
    }%
}

\renewcommand\maketitle{
\begin{titlepage}
    \newgeometry{left=18mm,top=20mm,right=10mm}
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth}
      \raisebox{\dimexpr \triangleH-\height\relax}{\includegraphics[width=5.66cm]{vub_logo_cmyk}}%
      \hfill%
      \vubtriangle
    \end{minipage}

    \vfill

    \hspace{25mm}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-58mm}
        \ifdefined\@pretitle%
            \vubfont\small\color{vuboranje}\@pretitle
        \fi

        \vubfontbf{\color{vubbleu}\flushleft{\Huge\expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{\@title}}}

        \vspace{5mm}

        {\color{vubbleu} \LARGE\vubfont\@subtitle}

        \vspace{3cm}

        {\color{vuboranje} \large\vubfont\@author}

        \vspace{5mm}

        {\color{vubbleu} \large\vubfont\@date}
    \end{minipage}

    \vfill

%    \hspace{25mm}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-58mm}
%        \ifdefined\@promotors%
%            \vubfont{\color{vubbleu}\@promotors}
%
%            \vspace{2mm}
%        \fi
%
%        \vubfontbf{\color{vubbleu}\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont \@faculty}
%    \end{minipage}

    \hspace{25mm}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-58mm}
        \ifdefined\@promotors%
                \vubfont{\color{vuboranje}Promotor:\\}
                %\vspace{1mm}
            \vubfont{\color{vubbleu}\@promotors}

            \vspace{2mm}
        \fi

        \vubfontbf{\color{vubbleu} \@faculty}
    \end{minipage}
    \restoregeometry
\end{titlepage}
}

\endinput
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: The abstract is structured as follows:

```
\section*{Abstract}
% ... large text that should fit one page ...
```

There are 6 lines that spill on to the next page.

To give you a visual clue of what's happening and why i think right-hand pages are less long, this is without a white page (so this is a left-hand page):

[image: Without white page]

With a white page (this is a right page):

[image]

Notice that i left the phrase that is common to both versions.

Comment: Please provide more information about what's in `abstract.tex`. Also, how long (how many rows?) is the paragraph that spills over onto the next page?

Comment: A separate comment: It's kind of weird to have both `\setcounter{page}{1}` *and* `\pagenumbering{roman}`, as the `\pagenumbering` macro automatically resets the value of the `page` counter to `1`.

Comment: Do you know about the `\enlargethispage` macro? If the number of rows spilling over to the next page of the Abstract isn't more than 2 or 3, try inserting `\enlargethispage{1.5\baselineskip}` immediately after `\section*{Abstract}` and check if the abstract material now fits on just one page. Or, just shorten the material in the abstract suitably...

Comment: @Mico thanks for pointing out. I added some images of what's actually happening. The problem is i already shortened the abstract remarkably that i cannot shorten it even more. But still, this should fit on one page since it works as you can see on the first image, but not on a right page for some reason. With the `enlargethispage` macro there are still 5 lines spilling over.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the full abstract page, not just the lower part.

Comment: @Mico added it :)

Comment: It very much looks like your preamble contains all kinds of stuff related to page layout and that this code is messing up the abstract page. Please edit your posting to show the preamble code. Otherwise, it's not possible to provide a good diagnosis of the problem, let alone suggest a cure.

Comment: @Mico I added it  now. I removed things that i know don't cause the problem, the packages that are still there are those i don't know what they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are changing the page geometry inside a group, the titlepage environment. This is wrong. Changing page geometry in the middle of a document is not easy and `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` should be always used at the document level. When used inside a group it leads to inconsistent  \textheight:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\newgeometry{left=18mm,top=20mm,right=10mm}
blub
\restoregeometry
\endgroup

\lipsum \lipsum \lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you correct the titlepage code the current abstract page will be shorter. So you will either have to shorten the abstract text or use `\enlargethispage` if you want to keep everything on one page.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I got unlucky that the left page showed a bug which allowed the entire abstract to fit on one page? :/

Comment: @kevindp - It's not a matter of a *bug*, i.e., of software not doing properly what it's supposed to do. Instead, it's a matter of incorrect coding.

Comment: @Mico Well one could claim that the `vub` package is buggy ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - You're right. :-)

Comment: Indeed, since i did not write that package i find it “buggy”.